# Firebase response is too slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, use-state

Hey Guys I'm using Firebase Realtime Database to fetch some data for my React.js Web App.

There is a `useState` called `Corr_User` that should store the value of correct username.

I have a `function` to fetch the username from Firebase : -

```
 function Login(){

       const path =  firebase.database().ref("users").child(username);
       
        path.once("value")
        .then(snapShot => {            
            setCorr_User(snapShot.child("username").val());
             
        })
```

When I do this  `console.log(Corr_User)` it prints  a empty string indicating that the `useState` is not updated.
For confirmation, I also logged the `snapshot.val()`. This printed the appropriate value.

I could understand from this that Firebase is too slow in returning response hence my `useState` is not getting updated. Is my understanding correct? Is there any way to make my `Login()` function wait for the response?

Please Help !! Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT -**
Ok there was a bit of confusion I guess. The code goes likes this

```
 function Login(){
....
.once("value")
.then(snapShot => { // After fetching the data
 
 setCorr_User(snapShot.child("username").val()); // Assigning the value

 console.log(snapShot.val()); // This should be logged first

}) // End of function snapShot()

// This is still inside Login()
 console.log(Corr_User) // But this is logged first

} // End of Login()
```

It is from this, I was able to guess that Firebase is too slow in responding and `useState` is not getting updated accordingly as `snapShot.val()` is still empty.

Comment: I'm guess you tried to `console.log` it on the next line after setting it? You can't do that, state changes are asynchronous

Comment: I did `console.log()` outside the function `snapShot` not inside that. Anyways How will I get to know whether the `useState` is updated or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, and the `then` is called when that data is available. What this means in practice is that your `console.log(Corr_User)` is called before `console.log(snapShot.val())`. For this reason, any code that needs data from the database must be inside the `then` callback, or be called from there.

This is an incredibly common stumbling block for developers new to asynchronous APIs, so I recommend studying some of these links:

- [Why Does Firebase Lose Reference outside the once() Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688268/why-does-firebase-lose-reference-outside-the-once-function/40688890#40688890)
- [Best way to retrieve Firebase data and return it, or an alternative way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905600/best-way-to-retrieve-firebase-data-and-return-it-or-an-alternative-way/34908497#34908497)
- [Firebase Query inside function returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381006/firebase-query-inside-function-returns-null/28382922#28382922)
- [Passing variable in parent scope to callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297654/passing-variable-in-parent-scope-to-callback-function/26299662#26299662)