# .$id retrieves but .name etc doesn't - AngularFire

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am attempting to retrieve data from firabase by getting the $id from routeparams and then syncing as object and retrieving individual pieces of the data with data.(childnamehere). This is successful when retrieving the meta i.e. data.$id but not when retrieving my own data i.e. data.name.. I have reviewed the documentation but can't figure out why I can't console.log (in this case) courseUnique.name ? Any help would be appreciated.

```
else if (action === "view") {
    var courseId = $routeParams.id;
    var sync = $firebase(coursesRef.child(courseId));
    var courseUnique = sync.$asObject();
    var id = courseUnique.$id;
    var name = courseUnique.name;
    console.log(courseId, courseUnique, id, name);
```

console output for above is:

```
-JhgqkeFyfvS9nh5bKyK FirebaseObject {$$conf: Object, $id: "-JhgqkeFyfvS9nh5bKyK", $priority: null, $save: function, $remove: function…} undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the terse answer, but this one has been covered a ton of times already. I'll provide some links to previous answer in a bit, but for now this code will work:

```
var courseUnique = sync.$asObject();
courseUnique.$loaded().then(function(courseUnique) {
    console.log(courseUnique.name);
})
```

See:

- [the AngularFire documentation for the `$loaded` event](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-loaded)
- [this blog post explaining the `$loaded` event](http://quabr.com/27658650/wait-for-loaded-data-and-then-return-in-angularfire-0-9-0)
- [this answer explaining why you need this `$loaded` construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049342/asynchronous-access-to-an-array-in-firebase/27050749#27050749)
- [most of these questions are probably about the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A209103%20%5Bangularfire%5D%20%24loaded)