# How to loop through $firebaseArray

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I created an array of users like so -

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users');
var users = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

I have added objects to this and I want to loop through each of the users in this array. I know this is possible in the view using ng-repeat, but I need to do it in the controller. I have tried -

```
angular.forEach(users, function(user) {
    console.log(user);
})
```

But I get no result from this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049342/asynchronous-access-to-an-array-in-firebase/27050749#27050749. But also note the second snippet on this documentation page: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro as it shows how best to debug data being loaded in an AngularJS/Firebase context: `<pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>`. `console.log` is not your best friend here.

Comment: Explained in the first page of the Angular guide and asked at least ten times here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Users probably isn't loaded by then, so you'll need to wait for it:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users');
var users = $firebaseArray(ref);

users.$loaded()
    .then(function(){
        angular.forEach(users, function(user) {
            console.log(user);
        })
    });
```

Here's the docs on it: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to accept the answer and upvotr it.

Comment: I accepted the answer, but unfortunately haven't got enough rep to upvote

Answer (score 2):

```
var fbref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/customers');
customers = $firebaseArray(fbref);

customers.$loaded()
.then(function(data){
    angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
        console.log('key='+key+', value='+value);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `$list` attribute,
e.g. The below function counts users,

```
app.factory("Users", function($firebaseArray) {
  return $firebaseArray.$extend({             
    getUsers: function() {
      var user_count = 0;
      angular.forEach(this.$list, function(user) {
        user_count += 1;
        console.log(user);
      });
      return user_count;
    }
  });
})
```

and then to use it,

```
var userList = new Users(ref);
userList.$loaded().then(function() {
  userList.getUsers();
});
```

Comment: Note that @ArupSaha is [extending the $firebaseArray service](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-extending-the-services) in this answer. The example is derived from the [documentation for `$firebaseArray.$extend`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-extending-the-services-firebasearrayextend).