# filter a $firebaseArray Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a service that I want to filter and array or data that I am pulling from firebase. I am new to firebase so I might be doing everything wrong I open to new ideas here is what my function in my service looks like.

```
public getSelectedHero(hero:string):CharacterCard[] {
  this.cards = firebase.database().ref().child('cards');

  this.selectionOfHeros = this.cards.filter(card => card.affiliation === hero);

  return this.selectionOfHeros;
}
```

So what I am trying to do is send in a parameter that will filter the array depending on what the user clicks.

I get an error saying that filter is not a function... but it is for array.

updated to this

```
 public getSelectedHero(hero:string):CharacterCard[] {
  let cards = firebase.database().ref('cards').once('value');

  cards.then(snap => {
    this.heroCards = snap.val();
    console.log(this.heroCards);
    this.selectionOfHeros = this.heroCards.filter(card => card.affiliation === hero);
  })

  console.log('selections' + this.selectionOfHeros)
  return this.selectionOfHeros;
}
```

Where the filter is is where I am having problems I just want to sort the array after I have taken a snap shot.

I found this through the documents, you can use orderByChild() and then set the equalTo() to sort the data base. This give me the data I want, but I don't really want to query the database, I want to manipulate the data on the web side.

```
    public getSelectedHero(hero:string):CharacterCard[] {
  let cards = firebase.database().ref('cards');

  cards.orderByChild('affiliation').equalTo(hero).on('value' , snap => {
    this.heroCards = snap.val();
  })

  return this.heroCards;
}
```

Comment: Firebase doesn't work like that. `child` returns a ref, not an array of data. You need to call `on` or `once` on the ref to access the data (via a callback or a promise). It's in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#reading_and_writing_data).

Comment: Even doing it that way I still get the error, If I store the data into an array I am not able to filter the array. Is their any way to make snap.val() an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the anuglarfire documentation a little, I started to wrap my head around how to put it into an array with the query calls. [docs](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/synchronized-arrays.md)

here is the code I ended up with

```
public getSelectedHero(hero:string):CharacterCard[] {
  let cards = firebase.database().ref().child('cards');
  let selectionQuery = cards.orderByChild('affiliation').equalTo(hero);

  this.selectionOfHeros = this.$firebaseArray(selectionQuery);

  return this.selectionOfHeros;  
}
```

Comment: This is funny though you cannot manipulate this.seelectionOfHeros. for example if I wanted to do a foreach on this.selectionOfHeros it will through the error this is not a function

Comment: I found my answer to my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061790/how-to-loop-through-firebasearray