# Firebase snapshot list undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have a problema with Firebase Api and `ref.on()` method for list snapshot list. Look:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html

**Rooms factory:**

```
.factory('Rooms', function ($firebaseObject, ObjectFactory) {
    var ref = new Firebase(firebaseUrl + '/rooms');

    var onComplete = function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Data could not be saved: ', error);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Data saved successfully!');
        }
    };

    return {
        all: function () {
            ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                return snapshot.val();
            }, function (errorObject) {
                console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
            });
        },
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('RoomsCtrl', function ($scope, Rooms, $state) {
        var rooms = Rooms.all();

        console.log('All Rooms:', rooms);
        console.log('Rooms length:', rooms);
```

**Output:**

```
All Rooms: undefined
Rooms length: undefined
```

or:

Added `$scope` in my `Rooms` controller and:

```
all: function () {
            $scope.result = {};

            ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                $scope.result = snapshot.val();
            }, function (errorObject) {
                console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
            });

            return $scope.result;
        },
```

but the problem is continuos `undefined` and the new problem is present:

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- Room`

I searched for already topic but I'm not finded nothing with this.

[Returning undefined object from a firebase snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949146/returning-undefined-object-from-a-firebase-snapshot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with your code. First, Rooms.all() does not actually return anything. Second, Firebase calls are asynchronous, so you need to either use AngularFire, $q, or wrap your function in $timeouts.

Here's an example using $firebaseArray.

```
.factory('Rooms', function ($firebaseArray) {
    var ref = new Firebase(firebaseUrl + '/rooms');

    return {
        all: function () {
            return $firebaseArray(ref);
        },
     }
 })


.controller('RoomsCtrl', function ($scope, Rooms, $state) {
     var $scope.rooms = Rooms.all();
 });
```

By binding `rooms` to the scope, you can see the output in your view. However, if you really want to use `console.log`, you'll want to use [$loaded()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-loaded) to log after data has been downloaded.

Comment: The problem is that I'm needing to use factory with controller and firebase data is not filtered for me. Nor with $loaded.

Comment: The output using Factory with snapshot.val(): All Rooms: anonymous(snapshot)