# GeoFire geoQuery returning data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, geofire

I'm newbie with Firebase + GeoFire and I'm having trouble with geoFire query function.

I want to add in an array the results from geoQuery function and return it in a function. But the data I have manipulating inside `geoQuery.on` method seems out of scope or not available or due to promises, I dont know... the fact is outside the geoquery.on method the variable sellers is empty.

How can I return results from geoQuery and save it into a return variable

```
//Set seller position in firebase db
var setPosition = function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPositionSuccess, error, options);
    //navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(setPositionSuccess, positionError, { enableHighAccuracy:true })
};  

//Get sellers near buyer position
var getSellersForCurrentPosition = function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPositionSuccess, error, options);
    //navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(positionSuccess, positionError, { enableHighAccuracy:true })
};  


//Callback function from html 5 geo api
function getPositionSuccess(pos) {

    var crd = pos.coords;
    var currentPosition = [crd.latitude, crd.longitude];

    // Query radius
    var radiusInKm = 2;

    var firebaseRef = new Firebase(FBURL + "/geofire/sellers/");
    var geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);

    var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
        center: currentPosition,
        radius: radiusInKm
    }); 

    var sellers = []; 
    var oneSeller = {}; 

    var onKeyEnteredRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
        oneSeller = { 
            id: key,
            distance: distance,
            location: location
        };  
        sellers.push(oneSeller);
    }); 

    var onReadyRegistration = geoQuery.on("ready", function() {
          geoQuery.cancel();
    });

    return sellers;

}
```

By the way, how accurate is html5 geolocation? Is it different between desktop browser and mobile browser?

Answer (score 0):

Geofire **monitors** the sellers in the range you indicate. Any time a seller enters/exits the range, it fires a `key_entered` or `key_exited` event. These events can happen at any time after you start the query. In JavaScript terms this is often described as: the callbacks happen *asynchronously*.

A simple event flow, might explain what happens best:

1. you call `getPositionSuccess()`
2. you **start** a Geoquery to monitor the sellers that are in range: `geoFire.query()`
3. no sellers are immediately in range, so your callback doesn't fire
4. the `getPositionSuccess()` function is done and exits
5. a seller comes in range
6. GeoFire fires the `key_entered` event and your callback runs
7. but `getPositionSuccess()` has already exited, so how can it return a value?

Even if you were to wait for the first seller to come into range before returning (not possible in a browser, but it *is* possible in other languages/environments), how will you return the value when a second seller comes in range?

For this reason, you have to deal with asynchronous data differently. Typically you do this by moving the code that would call the `getPositionSuccess()` function *into* the function.

Say you are now trying to do this:

```
var sellers = getPositionSuccess(pos);
sellers.forEach(function(seller) {
  addSellerToMap(seller);
});
```

To handle the asynchronous nature of the events, you'd move this code *into* `getPositionSuccess`:

```
//Callback function from html 5 geo api
function getPositionSuccess(pos) {
    var crd = pos.coords;
    var currentPosition = [crd.latitude, crd.longitude];

    // Query radius
    var radiusInKm = 2;

    var firebaseRef = new Firebase(FBURL + "/geofire/sellers/");
    var geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);

    var geoQuery = geoFire.query({
        center: currentPosition,
        radius: radiusInKm
    }); 

    var oneSeller = {}; 

    geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
        oneSeller = { 
            id: key,
            distance: distance,
            location: location
        };  
        addSellerToMap(oneSeller);
    }); 
}
```

I understand that in your use-case your sellers won't move, so it may be more intuitive to think of them as a static list. But even in this case, the results are loaded from a remote database and it will take some time before that data is loaded. The modern web loads data asynchronously and all your code will have to deal with it in a way similar to what I outlined above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At first, I have dealing with static sellers to do it more easily but the idea is that they are in movement, so I will use watchPosition html5 geo api method. So, let's say I have a node with sellers and their positions being updated in firebase db. Then, a buyer makes a request, html5 api takes its current position and geoQuery shows sellers who have close. I will not add they on a map, just get their ID's. So I need to return an array. Thanks and sorry for my english :{

Comment: All sounds like a perfectly valid use-case. But unfortunately: the modern web in general and Firebase in particular are asynchronous in nature. You *cannot* synchronously return data that is loaded asynchronously. All you can do is update a central location and then let the code that needs to know about the updated data know about it. So where it says `addSellerToMap` you can also put `tellBuyerThatASellerWasFound`.

Comment: You will have to come to grips with asynchronous programming. For a good answer that covers it in a slightly different context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049342/asynchronous-access-to-an-array-in-firebase/27050749#27050749. For a primer not related to Firebase, but equally relevant, read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?lq=1

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the links, but I think my problem is easier. Look at the first answer in this link, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/VUdy5yAhN1k this is just what I want, but sellers variable is empty outside geoQuery.on method, should we use a $scope variable? In geoQuery.on("ready", callback) I get sellers variable but i need make a return to load $scope.sellers variable in the SellerCtrl controller