# Firebase JWT Authentication

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

In my application I don't have user login, but I want to secure my Firebase data. I use for this Firebase Token Generator - PHP. Access to the database is like Russian roulette. Once I have permissions, once not when I'm refreshing page.

here is my token generator file:

```
<?php
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use Firebase\Token\TokenException;
    use Firebase\Token\TokenGenerator;

    try {
        $generator = new TokenGenerator('Firebase-Secret');
        $token = $generator
            ->setData(array('uid' => '123'))
            ->setOption('admin', true)
            ->create();
    } catch (TokenException $e) {
        echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    }

    echo $token;

?>
```

here is index.php:

```
<script>var token = "<?= include_once 'getToken.php' ?>";</script>

$(document).ready(function(){

        firebaseRef.authWithCustomToken(token, function(error, authData) {
            console.log(authData)
        }, {remember: "sessionOnly" });


            // do something
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Is there an actual question in there? I don't see any question mark. 
Also, if you have any more info, go ahead and edit the original. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please include a [minimal, complete repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your debugging issues. Most likely, you are running into [asynchronous issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049342/asynchronous-access-to-an-array-in-firebase/27050749#27050749). Your `//do something` code probably needs to move into the callback for auth.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  firebaseRef.authWithCustomToken(token, function(error, authData) {
      console.log(authData);

      if( !error ) {
         // run your authenticated code here
      }

  }, {remember: "sessionOnly" });

  // trying to run something here that requires auth will
  // be non-deterministic

});
```

Comment: I tried authenticate before token was generated, now I'm getting token by ajax and auth in .done()