# Why isn't it possible to access $value of a Firebase object from a controller?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have a function in my application that returns the first name of a user as a Firebase object:

```
function getFirstName(uid) {
    var userNameRef = Ref.child('users/' + uid + '/firstName');;
    return $firebaseObject(userNameRef);
}
```

Why can I only access `$value` from the HTML view, but not from a controller like this:

```
var firstName = getFirstName(uid);
$scope.firstName = firstName.$value;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous access to an array in Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049342/asynchronous-access-to-an-array-in-firebase)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access it in a controller, but it loads asynchronously so you'd have to use a promise. You should only do this if you absolutely need the value in your controller.

```
getFirstName(uid).$loaded().then(function(firstName) {
  console.log(firstName.$value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Totally forgot about the $loaded() callback