# Taking long to load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

This is getting very very very annoying now... Im stuck on this for a long time... The problem is it is getting slow on loading.. This is my code i will explain at the bottom about it:

```
app.controller('chatCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {


        var ref = new Firebase('MYFIREBASEAPP')
        $scope.usernameProfile = ''
        $scope.imageProfile = ''


        ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
            ref.child("Users Auth Info").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
                $scope.usernameProfile = snapshot.val().Username;
                $scope.imageProfile = snapshot.val().Image
                console.log(snapshot.val().Image)
                console.log(snapshot.val())
                console.log($scope.usernameProfile)
                var username = $scope.usernameProfile
                console.log($scope.imageProfile)
            })
        })


        console.log($scope.usernameProfile)
        console.log($scope.imageProfile)

    }])
```

Here i am getting the usernameProfile and imageProfile from the data of the user... The problem here is that it loads wayyy to slow.. that when i try to render it to html by passing:

```
<img id="profileImage" ng-src="{{imageProfile }}"  >
```

The image becomes blank.. for some reason the html dosent recognize the ng-model... also in my code above the ones at the bottom gets logged first then the others in the snapshot.val().. Please Please Help me.. Thankyou

### EDIT

Tried this... still dosent work...

```
   var ref = new Firebase('https://sparke.firebaseio.com/')
    var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);

    ref.onAuth(function(authData){
      $scope.profile = $firebaseObject(ref.child('UsersAuthInfo').child(authData.uid).child("Image"));
    $scope.profile.$loaded().then(function() {
        console.log($scope.profile.$value);
        $scope.imageProfile = $scope.profile.$value
        });
    })
```

### EDIT

This dosent work:

```
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
             console.log("Good?)
  ref.child("UsersAuthInfo").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
      $timeout(function() {
      $scope.usernameProfile = snapshot.val().Username;
      $scope.imageProfile = snapshot.val().Image
      console.log(snapshot.val())
    });
  })
})

console.log($scope.usernameProfile)
```

The one at the first which says Good, gets executed first then the bottom one then the one inside .child()

### EDIT3

Ok frank. Before i started, i just deleted the quotes and made it simpler...

Lets get started with the problem of $timeout...

So when i tested the $timeout for the original plunker(the simpler version...) It worked really fine This is the code:

```
ref.child('Image').on("value", function(snapshot) {
  // tell AngularJS that we're going to make changes to $scope
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.image = snapshot.val();
    console.log(snapshot.val())
  });
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
})
```

Now with the timeout when i tried to implement that to my original app it didnt work unforutunately for some reason... here is the code for that..:

```
ref.onAuth(function(authData){
  ref.child("UsersAuthInfo").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    // tell AngularJS that we're going to make changes to $scope
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.imageProfile = snapshot.val().Image;
      console.log(snapshot.val())
    });
  }, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
  })
})
```

Now with the $firebaseObject...

The $firebaseObject didnt even work for my Simpler version of the plunker as when i put in this code:

```
$scope.image = $firebaseObject(ref.child('Image'));
```

It gave me a blank picture... meaning the default picture when the url is not right... And i have noticed that the problem with that is when i console.log() the $scope.image like this:

```
console.log($scope.image)
```

I get an object... not a value.. The object is like this:

```
 $$conf: Object
$id: "Image"
$priority: null
$value: "http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/151/man-avatar-profile-picture-vector_151265384.jpg"
__proto__: Object
```

Help would be appreciated in either methods

### EDIT 4:

Ok so now i managed to get the Image (The simple plunker i showed you) on the plunker... Here is the code for that:

```
var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);
obj.$loaded(
  function(data) {
    $scope.image = data.Image
  },
  function(error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
);
```

But again when i tried to do that on my actuall app im working on it still dosent work!!! This is my code on the app im working on...:

```
ref.onAuth(function(authData){
    var obj = $firebaseObject(ref.child("UsersAuthInfo").child(authData.uid));
    obj.$loaded(
    function(data) {
      $scope.imageProfile = data.Image
      console.log(data.Image)
    },
    function(error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  );
})
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: How large is your image?

Comment: The default image is just this: http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/151/man-avatar-profile-picture-vector_151265384.jpg  @danday74

Comment: I'm on an iPad so I can't check file size but if the image is massive which many are today then that could be your issue

Comment: @danday74 - FYI the image is 1.7kb

Comment: `the ones at the bottom gets logged first` that can easily be explained by the nature of asynchronous code

Comment: *"the html dosent recognize the ng-model"* What `ng-model`? There is none shown. It looks like you are using code outside of angular context to update scope which requires notifying angular to run digest

Comment: the order of console.log? it's not broken, it's doing what it should when it should ... the general problem ... haven't looked hard enough yet

Comment: Suggest you convert to using angular fire

Comment: then google it ... firebase has an angular adapter and if you don't use it you need to run digests every time you update scope

Comment: Well you aren't using it in your controller, it's not being injected

Comment: Sure they do...I'm looking at the quick start guide right now

Comment: Thats $firebaseObject... i dont need that... i think.. ima test it out real quick and update with results

Comment: And that's why the docs say use `$firebaseAuth` .... you have to read them

Comment: I've never even used it and found all this in 3 minutes by reading the quick start guide

Comment: why wouldn't it when the docs saay it wraps the whole authentication api

Comment: So the docs are not telling the truth?

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

Comment: try usng `$apply()` with the current code you have as short term workaround

Comment: need a demo to see what issue is then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase loads the data asynchronously, which is why you have to attach a callback function:

```
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  ref.child("Users Auth Info").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    $scope.usernameProfile = snapshot.val().Username;
    $scope.imageProfile = snapshot.val().Image
  })
})
```

The problem is that by the time your callback is executed, AngularJS is not listening for changes anymore. So your `console.log` statement probably write out the values fine, the new values are bound to `$scope`, but AngularJS is simply not updating the views.

This can be fixed, by telling AngularJS that is needs to update the view in its next update cycle:

```
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  ref.child("Users Auth Info").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.usernameProfile = snapshot.val().Username;
      $scope.imageProfile = snapshot.val().Image
    });
  })
})
```

Alternatively, you can use AngularFire to accomplish the same.

For a longer explanation and a list of related questions, see [Asynchronous access to an array in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049342/asynchronous-access-to-an-array-in-firebase)

### Update

Your minimal code from the Plunkr is:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://angularfireauthtut.firebaseio.com/')
  $timeout(function(){
    ref.child('Image').on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    $scope.image = snapshot.val();
  }, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
  })
})

console.log("For some reason this gets logged first?")
console.log($scope.image)
```

For any next question, make *that* the only code in your question and we can get somewhere faster.

There are two problems in here, one is visible in the output from `console.log(snapshot.val());`:

> 'http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/151/man-avatar-profile-picture-vector_151265384.jpg'

See those single quotes around there? Those are not supposed to be there, because your HTML now ends up like this:

```
<img src="'http://png.clipart.me/graphics/thumbs/151/man-avatar-profile-picture-vector_151265384.jpg''" />
```

The src is surrounded by both double quotes and then single quotes and this means it's not a valid URL anymore.

The proper solution is to store the image without the single quotes. But for now, this will also work:

```
var imgUrl = snapshot.val();
imgUrl = imgUrl.substring(1, imgUrl.length-1);
$scope.image = imgUrl;
```

The second problem is that you fail to alert AngularJS of the new image. You've put the `$timeout` on the wrong level, it needs to be inside the value callback:

```
ref.child('Image').on("value", function(snapshot) {
  // tell AngularJS that we're going to make changes to $scope
  $timeout(function(){
    var imgUrl = snapshot.val();
    imgUrl = imgUrl.substring(1, imgUrl.length-1);
    console.log(imgUrl);
    $scope.image = imgUrl;
  });
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
})
```

This snippet works and shows your image.

Once you fix the data to not have the single quotes around the `Image` value anymore, you can get rid of most of this plumbing by using [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/):

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://angularfireauthtut.firebaseio.com/');
$scope.image = $firebaseObject(ref.child('Image'));
```

I highly recommend that you use that library. But if you don't, read up on `$timeout()` and AngularFire's digest loop before continuing. Just copying my working snippet without learning about those is guaranteed to lead to an equally frustrating experience soon again.

**update for EDIT3**

Since your database contains just strings, you'll need to use this in your HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{image.$value}}"/>
```

Updated working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/NlDsxdCqUSboZci6T7ES?p=preview

Comment: Did you consider what you can do to make it easier for us to help you? Can you reproduce your problem in a *minimal* jsfiddle/jsbin? That will make it more likely that someone is willing to have another look.

Comment: So minimize the code needed to reproduce the problem and create a jsfiddle. Don't just dump your code in there, spend time to isolate the problem. That means that both you gain a better understanding of the problem and it minimizes the effort you require from those who are trying to help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Good start. Now minimize the code in there. I doubt the `authWithPassword()` and `onAuth()` bits matters, so create the same problem without that. Then remove most of the JavaScript/CSS/HTML, because they likely have nothing to do with the problem either. The recipe is really there in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I'll add one more update, but then I've done as much as I can here. I understand that you're making quite a journey, but I cannot make it with you any further.  You'll have to *read* the documentation and do what it says there. `console.log($scope.image)` is not the way to debug AngularFire, which is why we say to in [step 2 of the programming guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-objects.html).

Comment: It works now Frank!! I just messud up on the Html!! Thanks a lot Your the best person alive!!!

Comment: If you're sorry, do as many have been telling you to do: read the documentation. Start with the [AngularFire quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html) and from there read the entire [AngularFire guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/). Stop doing your project, until you've completed the documentation.

Comment: Ok Frank! Ill complete the Guide and QuickStart!!