# Why is $firebaseArray slow on display?

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

Let me first say that I am new to firebase. As I have been playing with angularfire for a bit, I noticed that $firebaseArray was kinda slow in my project...

But when I used the console to find *when* the result from firebase was received , I realized that there was a second before that result was displayed in ionic view after it arrived.

If what i'm saying is not really clear, here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Eram90/pen/rxEwmE?editors=1010) with the $firebaseArray

```
var lists = $firebaseArray(ref.child('lists'));
```

And here is an other [codepen] (sorry can't add more than two links) where I added this line *after* it

`lists = [{"name":"test"}];`

There is an alert and console log in both codepen that shows when the data arrived.

What I'm asking is : *why* is there a second delay *after* the data has already arrived ?

**EDIT :**

Because 'slow' does not really mean anything, I took a screenshot of my browser's network for the first codepen, showing how much time was needed to display the data :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymPK5.jpg)

Comment: "slow" is highly subjective. What action do you measure? How long does it take? How long would you expect it to take? Also note that while it's great that you added a link to a codepen, your question should include the minimum code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I mean 'slow' because the data has _already arrived_ from firebase (in my codepen it is available when the alert comes up) and then there is a time before it is displayed (it takes about 1 or 2 seconds for it to be displayed. Which I think is a _lot_, since the data has already arrived. All it needs to do is display it, but it still takes seconds to do it). So I tried doing it with a local JSON array, and this time after the data is availeable (same alert) it displays instantly...

Comment: It shows fast for me in like 0..0001 miliseconds... Its probably something to do with your computer. I cant say anything about that..

Comment: @Dsafds the _first_ codepen takes milliseconds (with $firebaseArray) ?? if you're talking about the second one (with JSON) then it's normal. But the first one, I actually tried on different computers which have different internet connections, and it still takes 1 second on a fast one and on a slower one it took _6 seconds_.

Comment: Yes it takes me about 0.3 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I wasn't really looking for it when I found this thread, the answer to my question was given here :

[Asynchronous access to an array in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049342/asynchronous-access-to-an-array-in-firebase?lq=1)

> By the time the browser executes your console.log(userTokens); the data most likely hasn't been loaded yet. So it just prints the object
>   to the console as a placeholder.
>
> By the time it gets to the for loop, the data may or may not yet have
>   been loaded from Firebase.
>
> At some point you clicked the arrow next to the logged userTokens. By
>   that time the data had loaded from Firebase and the console shows the
>   latest data.

So anyway, thank you for your help in trying to answer my question :)